# Regex.Replace to replace sub-string in a string

Tags: c#

I am trying to replace ValueBinding="metasys-value:111,813? in following string

```
Canvas.Top="494" Width="75" Height="75" jcge:RubberBand.ID="ce4f76db-9efc-4b5d-b48b-b62f727d53ef"  ValueBinding="meta-value:111,813?analogCommand=37&amp;enumCommand=37" AlarmBinding="meta-item:Alarm%20-%20Present%20Value" TrendBinding="meta-item:Trend%20-%20Present%20Value"  SecondaryValueBinding="meta-value:222,813?analogCommand=10&amp;enumCommand=44" SecondaryTrendBinding="meta-item:Trend%20-%20Present%20Value" SensorType="Bulb"
```

by new string by using

```
patch = Regex.Replace(patch, "ValueBinding=" + "\".*,813", "ValueBinding=" + "\"" + primaryObjectReference + ",813");
```

but it replace string till second ,813 occurrence. how can I replace only `ValueBinding="metasys-value:111,813?` with new value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[^\"]*` or `.*?` instead of `.*` and add `\b` to the start of the regex.

`\b` matches a word boundary, eg. the space before `ValueBinding`.

`[^\"]*` will match all characters except `"`, `.*?` will match everything non greedily.

In your case:

```
patch = Regex.Replace(patch, "\\bValueBinding=" + "\".*?,813", "ValueBinding=" + "\"" + primaryObjectReference + ",813");
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine but replace both the occurrence how can I overcome that problem. That means it replace ValueBinding="metasys-value:111,813? and  SecondaryValueBinding="metasys-value:222,813? by new one.

Comment: put a `\b`in front of the regex

Comment: \b in front of regex? I dont get it.

Comment: It doesnt work with your given example it dont replace the values. patch = Regex.Replace(patch, "\bValueBinding=" + "\".*?,813", "ValueBinding=" + "\"" + primaryObjectReference + ",813");

Comment: I forgot to escape the \ in \b, it should be \\b

Answer (score 0):

This sounds logic because in you expression you have ".*,813", which will much 111,813 and 222,813 as well. If i have understand it well, you must replace ".*,813" with ".*111,813\?".